# Convert excel formulas to web based application

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel-formula, cells

I have an excel sheet where there are few formulas applied on each cells and now I want to convert them into a web based application.

Everything seems fine but there are few cells which has formulas which are dependent on each other.

Ex,

**Input cells:**

*Cost: 9790

Allocation: 3%

Non-Allocation: 97%*

**Cells with formula:**

Cell-1: **(Cell-3 * Allocation)** =  (10000 * 3%)
Result: $300

Cell-2: **(Non-Allocation * Cell-3)** = (10000 * 97%)
Result: $9700

Cell-3: **(Cost + Cell-1 - Fee on Damage)** = (9790 + 300 - 90)
Result: $10000

So here how will I calculate the dependent cell values as Cell-1 is dependent on Cell-3 and Cell-3 is dependent on Cell-1 ?

***EDIT:***

*Fee On Damage*: **(Total Fee * Allocation)**
And *Total Fee*: **calculated based on Cell-3 (Conditions like if Cell-3 <= 10000 then 3000 etc.)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't tag JavaScript, but here's a client-side JS solution, which could easily be implemented in c# or asp.net:

```js
var Cost = 9790,
    Allocation = 0.03,
    Fee = 90,
    C1 = 0,
    C3 = 0,
    C1iterations = 100,
    C3iterations = 100;

function Cell1() {
  if(--C1iterations) {
    C1 = Cell3() * Allocation;
  }
  else {
    C1iterations = 100;
  }
  return C1;
}

function Cell3() {
  if(--C3iterations) {
    C3 = Cost + Cell1() - Fee;
  }
  else {
    C3iterations = 100;
  }
  return C3;
}

document.body.innerHTML= 'Cell1: '+Cell1()+'<br>Cell3: '+Cell3();
```

You can tell Excel to allow circular references, in which case it defaults to 100 iterations.  This code duplicates that functionality, so you don't have to work through the algebra.

All variables are global for demonstration purposes, but they could easily be made local by using closures.

Comment: Ok. Will it be implemented in asp.net code-behind instead of javascript ??

Comment: In Classic ASP, you could use the code as-is, by putting it within `<script>...</script>` tags (and outside `<%...%>` tags).  I assume ASP.net works similarly.  The client computer would then do the calculations.  If you prefer to hide the calculations, you could rewrite the functions using ASP syntax.

Comment: +1 It has helped me to think on that direction. somehow around 99%, I have solved it.!! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I did not know that excel can to something like this but so be it.

It turns out that this is a simple excercise in school-algebra:

- let's give **Cell-3** the variable `z`
- and **Cell-1** the variable `x`

then you have the formulas:

```
x = z*Allocation
```

and

```
z = Cost + x - Fee
```

and so you can plug in the later into the first and get:

```
x = (Cost + x - Fee) * Allocation
```

get all `x` on the left side:

```
(1-Allocation)*x = (Cost - Fee) * Allocation
```

and divide

```
x = (Cost - Fee) * Allocation / (1-Allocation)
```

no plug into z:

```
z = Cost - Fee + (Cost - Fee) * Allocation / (1-Allocation)
```

(you can simplify the last too)

so let's check with `Cost = 9790`, `Fee = 90` and `Allocation = 0.03`:

```
x = 9700 * 0.03 / 0.97 = 300
z = 9700 + 300 = 10000
```

seems right.

#### Remark

Obvious it's much harder to this this using some kind of auto-convert tool you might want to write in some common programming language like C#, as you'd need to teach your programm how to do basic algebra ;) - but if you only have a few of those cells and just want to translate it you can do it manually.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer which works but with one fixed value `Fee on Damage` which is also calculated based on other cells. I have made an edit on the question. Can you please help me to solve this out then I will accept this answer.

Comment: I don't see all your conditions (I'm really impressed that excel can handle this stuff - have to try it at some time) - basically conditions like this make the *calculation* way harder as you have to take care of a case analysis by hand - and here it's getting even worse because you get an iterative formula and have to look for a fixed point (excel: really? wow!) - are you sure that you had this in excel?

Comment: Yes. Because excel will re-calculate the values on each cell's value will change. If you skip the conditions and if I only want to get `Fee on damage` then can you please help me out ?

Comment: @VishalSuthar if `Fee on damage` don't depend on any other cell than it's what I gave you

Comment: `Fee on damage  = Total Fee * Allocation` but `Total Fee` is calculated from `Cell-3` and this `fee on damage` is being used in `x` and `z` also.